# I want to access the information of the desired account on Instagram with python

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram-api

I want to access the information of an account on Instagram with python requests. I can access the userid, but when I try to access the information of the account, I get an error. I'm not even sure if I'm doing it with a single sign-on. What I want to do is how do I log in to my Instagram account and make transactions with it?

```
import requests

import re

s = requests.session()

s.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

payload = {
"enc_password":"#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:0:hello123",
"queryParams": {},
"trustedDeviceRecords": {},
"username": "censor",
}

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}


cookie_cek = s.get(
    "https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/web/accounts/login/ajax/", headers=headers
)

csrftoken = s.cookies.get("csrftoken")

headers2 = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
"x-csrftoken": csrftoken,
}

r = s.post(
    "https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/web/accounts/login/ajax/",
    data=payload,
    headers=headers2,
)

print(r.text)

cookies_cek = s.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

cookie_list = "; ".join([f"{cookie.name}={cookie.value}" for cookie in s.cookies])

# print(cookie_list)

hesap_bilgisi_cek = s.get("https://www.instagram.com/kevin/")

search_pattern = re.compile(rb'"id":"(\d+)"')

match = search_pattern.search(hesap_bilgisi_cek.content)

if match:

    userid = match.group(1).decode("utf-8")

    print("userid:", userid)

else:

    print("error.")


get_account_info = s.get(
    "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/" + userid + "/info/", headers=headers2
)

print(get_account_info.content)
```

output is like this:

```
{"user":true,"userId":"censor","authenticated":true,"oneTapPrompt":true,"status":"ok"}

userid: 3

b'{"message":"useragent mismatch","status":"fail"}'

[Program finished]
```

I want to access the information of the account I want without any problems.

error = b'{"message":"useragent mismatch","status":"fail"}'

Comment: Can you format your code so that we don't have to scroll as much?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: b'{"message":"useragent mismatch","status":"fail"}' its error

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved the problem, if you are getting this problem, you can use the official user agents, here is an example:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 105.0.0.11.118 (iPhone11,8; iOS 12_3_1; en_US; en-US; scale =2.00; 828x1792; 165586599)